# Do you need a webserver to run PHP files through an html POST?

Tags: centos, php

I'm doing some web development testing locally in `/home/test/index.html` and I have a `<form>` that POSTs to a php file in the same directory. I'm not using a webserver or localhost but I do have it installed.

When I submit this form, the browser displaying the local file asks me to download the php file instead of running it. How can I have the computer run the PHP file instead?

I know that PHP works because when I put the files in the web directory `/var/www/` everything works.

Running `php -v` outputs `PHP 5.3.3 (cli)` and I'm on CentOS 6.8

Comment: Yes, you'll need to be running *some* sort of webserver for that. PHP comes with a super-simple, development-only one. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Side note: PHP 5.3?!  That was end-of-lifed in 2014. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: Thanks I'd love to use PHP's webserver but yeah.. it's not my choice to run CentOS 6.8 which defaults to installing 5.3. I'm using apache now and made sym links to the web directory and they run fine.

Comment: You can always replace the PHP version with something more current. And you should.